# Spring Boot logging to elasticsearch server using bulk endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana, logback

I am new to Spring Boot / ELK and I'm probably missing something. Basically I have a Spring Boot APP and I want to submit the logs of the app to ElasticSearch so that I can see it in Kibana.
I have created a ElasticSearch server via docker:

```
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2
    network_mode: bridge
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
      - "4571:4571"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - SERVICES=es
      - ELASTICSEARCH_BACKEND=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR- }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR}
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    links:
      - elasticsearch

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
```

Running this docker compose generates me an ElasticSearch host `http://mylogs-2.us-east-1.es.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/` and I created (PUT) an index my-index in this elastic.

Then I'm trying to configure my app to point to the bulk [url property] endpoint using `logback-spring.xml` :

```
<appender name="ELASTIC" class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAppender">
    <url>http://mylogs-2.us-east-1.es.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/my-index/_bulk</url>
    <index>logs-%date{yyyy-MM-dd}</index>
    <type>tester</type>
    <loggerName>es-logger</loggerName> <!-- optional -->
    <errorLoggerName>es-error-logger</errorLoggerName> <!-- optional -->
    <connectTimeout>30000</connectTimeout> <!-- optional (in ms, default 30000) -->
    <errorsToStderr>false</errorsToStderr> <!-- optional (default false) -->
    <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData> <!-- optional (default false) -->
    <logsToStderr>false</logsToStderr> <!-- optional (default false) -->
    <maxQueueSize>104857600</maxQueueSize> <!-- optional (default 104857600) -->
    <maxRetries>3</maxRetries> <!-- optional (default 3) -->
    <readTimeout>30000</readTimeout> <!-- optional (in ms, default 30000) -->
    <sleepTime>250</sleepTime> <!-- optional (in ms, default 250) -->
    <rawJsonMessage>true</rawJsonMessage> <!-- optional (default false) -->
    <includeMdc>false</includeMdc> <!-- optional (default false) -->
    <maxMessageSize>100</maxMessageSize> <!-- optional (default -1 -->
    <authentication class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.config.BasicAuthentication" /> <!-- optional -->
    <headers>
      <header>
        <name>Content-Type</name>
        <value>application/x-ndjson</value>
      </header>
    </headers>
  </appender>

... 

  <logger name="es-logger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="ELASTIC" />
  </logger>
```

And I start Kibana with kibana.yml pointing to this elastic host. File looks like:

elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://mylogs-2.us-east-1.es.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566"]

However I cannot see the logs in Kibana when I start my spring boot app (and trigger the endpoint which uses a org.slf4j.Logger to log)

NOTE: When I manually POST data to the bulk endpoint in Postman works fine

POST http://mylogs-2.us-east-1.es.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/my-index/_bulk
´´´
{ "index": {} }
{ "name": "Test33", "data": "This is my test data333" }
´´´

I tried looking online but I couldnt find a specific example on how to use this logback and bulk endpoint.
What am I missing? Is it not the right way to post to bulk endpoint?

Thanks for reading all this

Comment: what is the output from the `_cat/indices?v` endpoint in Elasticsearch?

Comment: @MarkWalkom hey, its too long but the indices displayed are .apm-custom-link 
.kibana_task_manager_1
my-index (yellow health), status open
 .apm-agent-configuration
 .ds-logs-2021-12-01-000001 (yellow, open)
 messages
 .async-search
 .kibana_1
 .kibana-event-log-7.10.2-000001

Comment: does `my_index` exist?

Comment: no, only my-index (hyphen)